# React JS Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mime, vite

React JS Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

I use react js with vite & this error occurred when I install Material Table to my packages.

[image]

Comment: You are serving your JS files with the wrong content type or not at all. Whats your server config? Whats the response?